# AutoLayout has buttons on top of each other

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, autolayout

I have constraints on my UIButtons in iPad app so that the top row of buttons stays a certain distance from the UIImageView, and so the bottom row of buttons stays pinned fairly close to the bottom.  However, when I rotate it goes all wrong.  Here is the image of when in Portrait and when in Landscape.  How can this be fixed, given the less amount of vertical real estate in landscape mode?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will either need to scale the size of your subviews upon rotation, or use a scroll-view.

Because you are positioning your buttons a certain distance from the bottom of the screen instead of keeping consistent spacing, they overlap when not enough space is available. (I'm assuming from your screenshots that it is breaking the constraint between the 2 rows of buttons, assuming there is one)

You can relate the available space for each row of buttons to the total vertical size of the main view. For instance, let the image be 50% of the total vertical space, and 25% to each row of buttons (I would set up a container view for each row and then add constraints to the containers). Make sure that your images/buttons properly scale and maintain their aspect ratio.

Another option could be to recognize when the view rotates, and modify all of the constraints so that your buttons all layout in a single row, but this could involve a decent amount of coding to swap/change most of your constraints.

Comment: There isn't currently a vertical constraint gap between each row of buttons.  How can that be added, or should it be added?  I use XIB and not Storyboard for this particular app, so it affects it somewhat to most of tutorials written now for AutoLayout.  What do you think the easiest method of this would be?  I would love to just have the one row when rotated, but don't know how to accomplish that.

Comment: Try putting a vertical constraint between each row of buttons. For instance, ctrl-drag from one button down to the one below it, and choose "vertical spacing" Then find the constraint in the Size Inspector, change the type from "Equal" to "Greater than or Equal" and set the constant to 0. See if that works for you. Though, depending on how other constraints are set up, this might not work.

Comment: @user717452 I see that both of your screenshots are from an iPad. If this is the only target device, another thing to consider would be to just put all 6 buttons in a single row whether in portrait or landscape as there will be ample space to do this on a larger iPad screen.